# Magento 2 - Enable/Disable COD option at store level from admin panel

Tags: magento2, multistore, payment-methods

In Magneto default Enable/disable any payment method can be handled as per the website.
But now we are in need to setup these functionalities as per store.
Is it possible to enable/disable payment method by store??

Please guide me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can override model file and do customization

Answer (score 0):

First, you can change configuration from system.xml

```
 <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
```

add  `showInStore="1"` in xml and later override payment model file based on your requirement.